# Using Bootstrap glyphicons with LoginStatus controller

Tags: vb.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

I'm currently in the process of updating and old webForms application and refreshing it and making it responsive using Bootstrap.

One issue I am having is applying a glyphicon image to a LoginStatus controller.

So far, I have the following code:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavigation">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li><a href="/Bookings/BookingsReport.aspx"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stats"></span> Bookings Report</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Announcements/AnnounceList.aspx"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-comment"></span> Announcements</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Links/UsefulLinks.aspx"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list"></span> Useful Links</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Hotels/HotelList.aspx"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-bed"></span> Hotel Amenities</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <asp:hyperlink runat="server" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" role="button" aria-expanded="false"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span> <%= Session("CustomerGreeting")%> <span class="caret"></span></asp:hyperlink>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li role="presentation" class="dropdown-header"></li>
                <li role="presentation"><asp:HyperLink ID="Button_Admin" runat="server" class="menuitem" Visible="false" NavigateUrl="~/Admin/Access/Users.aspx">Admin</asp:HyperLink></li>
                <li role="presentation"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span><asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" class="menuitem" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutPageUrl="~/Login.aspx" /></li> 
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

As you can see, with Hyperlinks it is fairly simple to nest the glyphicons within the link creating a nice presentation effect however with a LoginStatus controller this is not possible due to the lack of a closing tag.

Does anyone know how this can be tweaked to achieve this? If not, how do I use a hyperlink to perform the logout action instead of a LoginStatus controller?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

N.B. My whole menu is already nested inside a LoginView so I don't think this would be an option in this case

Answer (score 2):

I just today faced that same and i achieved this by modifying the LogOutText to this `LogoutText="&lt;i aria-hidden=&quot;true&quot; class=&quot;glyphicon glyphicon-log-out&quot;&gt;&lt;/i&gt;Log out"`

maybe you will need to put the  before .. because I was doing some thin in RTL.